# How to merge fiber subtools in Zbrush

Tags: models, 3d-modeling, zbrush

I just started learning Zbrush.

While using Fibermesh, I notice that the "fiber" subtools are different from the normal ones. For example, they can be exported as curves, and BPR renders them differently.

However, when I try to merge two fiber subtools, they become a normal subtool, i.e. all fibers become normal polygons. I can no longer treat it as fibers, nor can I export it as curves.

Is there a way to merge multiple fiber subtools into one?

A related question might be: is there a way to import an obj file into Zbrush, so that it becomes a fiber subtool?

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to overcome this.

While using "merge down" will destroy the fibers, using "merge visible" seems to keep them still as fibers.